# C confused about bitwise shift operation

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

In a book I am reading, there is a hash function shown below

```
static inline ulong zend_inline_hash_func(const char *arKey, uint nKeyLength)
{
    register ulong hash = 5381;

    for (uint i = 0; i < nKeyLength; ++i) {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + arKey[i];
    }
    return hash;
}
```

> The `hash << 5 + hash` expression is the same as `hash * 32 + hash` or just `hash * 33`.

I understand why `hash << 5 + hash` is the same as `hash * 32 + hash`, but how it become `hash * 33` is the what I dont understand.
I tried to reason that `hash * 32` overflows and wraps to become modulo 2^n operation, but clearly that's not because a) the `hash` is of type `ulong`
which is big enough to hold the results of `hash *32` expression. b) even `unint` is still big to overflow by the multiplication in question
Can someone with more C knowledge help me out with a simple explanation and maybe even point out the source of my confusion.
Thank yoou.

Comment: Um, hash*32+hash is the same as hash*(32+1) mathematically...

Comment: I mean you figured that hash<<5 is the same as hash*32. Now you have hash*32+hash. Let hash be a common factor. It thus becomes hash*(32+1) or hash*33

Comment: Mathematically X * 32 + X = X * 33. No magic.

Comment: @PaulStelian where is  `hash` changing to become  1

Comment: Well hash == hash*1? I think basic arithmetic may need to be studied again...

Comment: Is it not clear that if you have 32 hashes and add another 1 has you have 33 hashes?

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic-- you are aware that `hash<<5` does not change the value of `hash`, but merely evaluates to the result?

Comment: @PaulStelian sorry  if the question sounds stupid, but I am thinking of `hash` as a variable with a value of 5381 in the above expression, so I am thinking this,`5381*32+5381`

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes, I am aware

Comment: BTW it is crucial that you write `(hash << 5) + hash` and do not "shorten" it to `hash << 5 + hash`

Comment: You do know that `2 + 2 + 2 = 3*2`, right? What is `2 + 2 + 2 + 2`? What then is `3 * 2 + 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is less to do with C, and more to do with mathematics.

> The hash << 5 + hash expression is the same as hash * 32 + hash or just hash * 33.

Basic algebra states these things are true (these are written in C):

```
/* #1 */ (a * b + a * c) == (a * (b + c))
/* #2 */ (a) == (a * 1)
```

Applying #2, we can say:

```
(hash * 32 + hash) == (hash * 32 + hash * 1)
```

Now applying #1, we can find:

```
(hash * 32 + hash * 1) == (hash * (32 + 1))
```

This can be reduced to:

```
hash * 33
```

This is basic mathematics, but maybe you are tired or overworked and just can't see how this works :)

Comment: Is this addition and multiplication rule only, I never came across before

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic That is the distributive law. You can learn a bit about it [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/associative-commutative-distributive.html).

Comment: Thanks. I now get it. I think is about to brush up my maths